# Instrumenting a file so that it loads with a fill column value of 67

Tags: emacs

How do you setup a file with hints so that it opens with a fill column of 67 instead of the default of 80?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set `fill-column` with a [file-local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).  There are two ways to do it.  Either include the following on the first line of the file:

```
-*- fill-column: 67 -*-
```

Or include a block like the following at the end of the file:

```
Local Variables:
fill-column: 67
End:
```

You could enclose either variant in the comment markers appropriate for the language you're using.

Comment: I just thought of one other thing I could do. Use a particular file suffix and then have some sort of minor mode set it through a hook. This would eliminate the need to instrument the file.